# Two 12.04 machines have the same display settings but different results

Tags: 12.04, unity, resolution, fonts, gnome-terminal

I have one machine that has a relatively fresh install of 12.04 and one that I inherited. The terminal window in the inherited machine has a really weird font, and the regular one is what I would expect. Especially the behavior of the "m" character is messed up. Note: both of these machines are on the same KVM switch.

Here is what I've tried:

1. MyUnity on both machines seem the same
2. .bashrc on both machines seem similar in all the ways that would matter for this issue
3. The terminal profiles on both machines are the default
4. Here are the xrandr outputs:

#### Good xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
   1280x1024      60.0 +   76.0     75.0*    72.0     70.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1
```

#### Bad xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
   1280x1024      60.0*+   76.0     75.0     72.0     70.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9
```

Finally here are screenshots of both machines, it seems to really only be Terminal, I have askubuntu behind the terminal window for comparison:

#### Good screenshot:

[image: Good computer screenshot]

#### Bad Screenshot:

[image: Bad computer screenshot]

Any thoughts as to what this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect that you have a problem in your font configuration. Your terminal may be looking for a font that is not present, or one with badly broken kerning.

Comment: I focused all my effort on fonts after this answer, and after trying to diagnose the differences for some time I finally tried `sudo apt-get install ttf-ubuntu-font-family` and that fixed it.